# Can not append a post in Rails using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I was trying to append a newly created post to the list once a user hits the submit button. However, the list will not be updated until I refresh the page, so I guess the problem must come from my javascript code.

In index.html.erb I put this line:

```
<div class="posts">
  <%= render :partial => 'post', :collection=> @posts %>
</div>
```

In create.js.erb:

```
 $(".posts").
   append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "post", :object => @post)%>");
```

The rest parts should be fine.

Do I need to put the js code in application.js?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can format code by indenting 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are including your javascript library

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

That needs to go in your header

Comment: Thank you for replying! I include this    config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jeditable rails application) in application.rb and I think it should serve the same purpose. And my destroy javascript effect actually works. So I assume not including javascript tag is not the issue??

Comment: if it is a specific library make sure that is working otherwise if it is defaults and your basic javascript/rails type stuff is working then

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking in your development.log file to make sure the method invokes the right template. Also open up your Javascript console in the browser and look for errors. Do  trial run of your jQuery code in the console too, to make sure your code works.

Comment: Thank you! I spotted an error after using console, so I changed "post" to 'post', and I also realize my "posts" div is not doing anything. So I give my post table a class name "posts", nothing happens except every time I run my code in console, it prints out <%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'post', :object => @post )%> at the end of table.

Comment: Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Nov 01 22:59:32 -0500 2010
  Processing by PostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"name"=>"test", "title"=>"test", "content"=>"test"}, "authenticity_token"=>"ztpjyzuMTVLfMBfgp7UO3QSCkW9PewW6JeSZXVWvxOw=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("content", "created_at", "name", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ('test', '2010-11-02 03:59:32.221059', 'test', 'test', '2010-11-02 03:59:32.221059')
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)